# Logging Block to NLog

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, nlog

I want to use NLog instead of default Logging Block in Exception Handling Block of Enterprise Library. Anybody have any advice or working example how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom exception handler that contains the appropriate NLog functionality.  The [Enterprise Library 5.0 - Extensibility Labs](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/58929) have samples on creating custom exception handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You add the NLog.dll

You set a config file

You create a static logger for each class :

```
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

And then you log :

```
_logger.Error("error");
```

Comment: How does that hook into the Enterprise Library Exception Handling Block?